# Insert value into array in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm working on a program that counts pixels and their RGB.
I'm trying to insert these values into a two-dimensional array, but after one loop the program throws the exception.
Why is that happening?

When I comment out the array line in the loop, it does not break.

```
package imaging;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.io.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Imaging3 {

    BufferedImage image;
    int width, heigth, test;
    int i, j;
    int[][] hor = new int[i][j];

    public Imaging3(){
        try {
            File input = new File("img1.png");
            image = ImageIO.read(input);
            width = image.getWidth();
            heigth = image.getHeight();

            int count = 0;

            System.out.println("Horizontal scan: ");

            for (i = 0; i < heigth; i++){
                for (j = 0; j < width; j++){

                    count++;
                    Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
                    System.out.println("nr " + count + "| " + c.getRed() + " " + c.getGreen() + " " + c.getBlue());
                    hor[i][j] = c.getRed();
                    }
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Program over");
        }
    }

    static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        Imaging3 obj = new Imaging3();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception?

Comment: Can you please share the stack trace for the error ?

Comment: It would be much easy for you if you read the text of the Exception. It usually says what exactly went wrong. For instance, you may want to use `new int[width][height];` instead of `new int[i][j];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when you initialize the array here:

```
int i, j;
int[][] hor = new int[i][j];
```

This can be read as:

```
int i, j=0;
int[][] hor = new int[0][0];
```

The default value of int is 0 so basically you create empty two dimensional array. When you try inserting values it throws exception.

To fix it move the initialization of the array in the code where you already know the height and width.

```
 width = image.getWidth();
 height= image.getHeight();

 int[][] hor = new int[height][width];
```

And remove these i,j on top. You don't need them ;) Define them for the loops only. A good practice is to define the variable where you need it and not on class level.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined i and j as class properties their default values are 0. So following line generate array of size 0 and 0 for both dimensions:

```
int[][] hor = new int[i][j];
```

Remove instantiation of array from property direct instantiation and new array right after reading width and height of your image, as follow:

```
public class Imaging3 {

    BufferedImage image;
    int test;
    int[][] hor;

    public Imaging3(){
        try {
            File input = new File("img1.png");
            image = ImageIO.read(input);
            int width = image.getWidth();
            int heigth = image.getHeight();

            hor = new int[height][width];

            int count = 0;

            System.out.println("Horizontal scan: ");

            for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){

                    count++;
                    Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
                    System.out.println("nr " + count + "| " + c.getRed() + " " + c.getGreen() + " " + c.getBlue());
                    hor[i][j] = c.getRed();
                    }
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Program over");
        }
    }

    static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        Imaging3 obj = new Imaging3();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not assign a value to i and j, so they are zero, the default value of the int type. Then the array hor become a 0*0 array.